# python - splitting dataframe to do monthly analyses

Tags: python, python-2.7

*Hey I am quite new to programming with python and have the following question:
I am trying to do analyses on a data-frame. My data has a time span of around 3 years. I created a boolean to do analyses for a certain threshold value. Now i want to do this same analyses but than for every month in my data, any tips?*

Sorry for the duplicate question, as I said, I am new to python and stackoverflow. I used the other post to code the following (see picture). I am  having troubles with using the list of monthly data as an input for the below boolean code to, which tests it to the threshold value of 1300?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiKsk.png)

Comment: Pandas ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21605491/how-to-split-a-pandas-dataframe-or-series-by-day-possibly-using-an-iterator

Comment: No data, no help.